# How to get TapPoints of User

Tags: c++, marmalade, tapjoy

I am using marmalade extension for TapJoy and using the SDK and sample project from [here](http://knowledge.tapjoy.com/integration-8-x/ios/tools-plugins-extensions/airplay-extension).
The function used here for getting TapPoints of user is:

```
 s3eResult TapjoyGetTapPoints(TapjoyGetTapPointsCallbackFn callbackFn, void* userData)
```

Which returns `s3eResult` type showing just success or failure of the query. But how do I get the actual points in int or any other number type?
What I am using is like this:

```
int TapJoy::GetPoints(){
s3eResult res=TapjoyGetTapPoints((TapjoyGetTapPointsCallbackFn)&TapJoy::GetTapPointsCB, NULL);
return GetTapPointsCB(NULL,NULL);
}
int32 TapJoy::GetTapPointsCB(TapjoyGetTapPointsResult* result, void* userData)
{
int tapPoints = result->m_PointTotal;

sprintf("Points", "`x666666Tap Points: %d", tapPoints);

s3eDebugTracePrintf("GetTapPointsCB called with amount: %d", tapPoints);
cout<<tapPoints<<endl;

return tapPoints;
}
```

The problem in this code is how do I get `TapjoyGetTapPointsResult* result`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I got this one right. `TapjoyGetTapPointsResult* result` is the struct which is sent by the `Tapjoy` once the request is finished and calls the callback function. So the TapPoints I can get using

```
result->m_PointTotal;
```

Leaving the question and answer, so that it can help other users in future.